# Simple example to get started with Angular data binding - why doesn't this work?

Tags: angularjs

Im getting started with Angular.js. I am trying the data binding that angular offers

With this code I expect that whatever I type in the dialogue box is rendered underneath in the browser. WHy isn't that happening here? What am I missing?

```
 <!Doctype html>
 <html ng-app>
 <head>
<title>Simple App</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

This is what Im seeing:

[image]

Comment: Is the page running on a server? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid but. Ive installed node and npm. How do I run a server?

Comment: I mean Wamp server or like that

Comment: Need do set ng-app somewhere, example <body ng-app=""> to tell angular that it can control that part of the dom

Comment: No this is just code in the browser, Im following in a tutorial

Comment: I just updated my code after adding ng-app. Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the browser console

Comment: Did adding `ng-app` fix your problem? If it does you should state so clearly, because editing your answer to include it might create confusion, when it was the most obvious omission in your question originally.

Comment: Nope adding ng-app didn't solve the problem. still the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">   </script>
```

should be

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **ng-app** in the html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Simple App</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js">   </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myapp">
<input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Added ng-app and it didnt do anything

Comment: How do you run this page?

Comment: im just refreshing the browser

Comment: No Im not using a wamp server. Im on a mac and I have installed node.js. How can I run server? Is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: There is no need for a server btw

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Working example